# How to read local JSON file and output JSON in swift?

Tags: json, swift

```
import Foundation

class ReadLocalJSON {

    static func readJSONFromFile(fileName: String) -> JSON
    {
        var json: JSON
        if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: fileName, ofType: "json") {
            do {
                let fileUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: fileUrl, options: .mappedIfSafe)
                json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)
            } catch {
                print("Something goes wrong when reading local json file.")
            }
        }
        return json
    }

}
```

I try to read the local json file and output json. But the line `json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)` gives an error saying `Cannot assign value of type 'Any?' to type 'JSON'`.

My json data looks like

```
{
    "leagues":
    [
        {   "name": "Hockey",
            "image": "hockey",
            "games":
            [
                {
                    "game_state": "Final",
                    "game_time": 1456662600,
                    "home_team_city": "Alberta",
                    "home_team_name": "Pigs",
                    "home_team_score": 1,
                    "home_team_logo": "pig",
                    "visit_team_city": "Montreal",
                    "visit_team_name": "Fishes",
                    "visit_team_score": 4,
                    "visit_team_logo": "fish"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

When I change the output type to be `Any?` I print the output and it seems missing some elements.

```
{
    leagues =     (
                {
            games =             (
                                {
                    "game_state" = Final;
                    "game_time" = 1456662600;
                    ...
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: can you please send a proper json ??

Comment: @Ankur Purwar I edit the json file already. Is the information enough?

Comment: So your problem is that you are not able to parse this json ?

Comment: Yes. Though I can parse it to `Any?`, I can't unwrap it and get the data inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the solution below, I used Codable for the JSON decoding.

```
import Foundation


struct Sports: Codable {
    let leagues: [League]
}


struct League: Codable {
    let name, image: String
    let games: [Game]
}


struct Game: Codable {
    let gameState: String
    let gameTime: Int
    let homeTeamCity, homeTeamName: String
    let homeTeamScore: Int
    let homeTeamLogo, visitTeamCity, visitTeamName: String
    let visitTeamScore: Int
    let visitTeamLogo: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case gameState = "game_state"
        case gameTime = "game_time"
        case homeTeamCity = "home_team_city"
        case homeTeamName = "home_team_name"
        case homeTeamScore = "home_team_score"
        case homeTeamLogo = "home_team_logo"
        case visitTeamCity = "visit_team_city"
        case visitTeamName = "visit_team_name"
        case visitTeamScore = "visit_team_score"
        case visitTeamLogo = "visit_team_logo"
    }
}

class ReadLocalJSON {

    static func readJSONFromFile(fileName: String) -> Sports?
    {
        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: fileName, ofType: "json")
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path!)
        let sportsData = try? Data(contentsOf: url)
        guard
            let data = sportsData
            else { return nil  }
        do {
            let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Sports.self, from: data)
            print(result)
            return result
        } catch let error {
            print("Failed to Decode Object", error)
            return nil
        }
    }
}


ReadLocalJSON.readJSONFromFile(fileName: "test")
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:- first make a modal class in your project

```
 struct Welcome: Codable {
        let leagues: [League]?
    }

    // MARK: - League
    struct League: Codable {
        let name, image: String?
        let games: [Game]?
    }

    // MARK: - Game
    struct Game: Codable {
        let gameState: String?
        let gameTime: Int?
        let homeTeamCity, homeTeamName: String?
        let homeTeamScore: Int?
        let homeTeamLogo, visitTeamCity, visitTeamName: String?
        let visitTeamScore: Int?
        let visitTeamLogo: String?

        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case gameState = "game_state"
            case gameTime = "game_time"
            case homeTeamCity = "home_team_city"
            case homeTeamName = "home_team_name"
            case homeTeamScore = "home_team_score"
            case homeTeamLogo = "home_team_logo"
            case visitTeamCity = "visit_team_city"
            case visitTeamName = "visit_team_name"
            case visitTeamScore = "visit_team_score"
            case visitTeamLogo = "visit_team_logo"
        }
    }
```

Step 2 : - After getting response write this line,

```
 let decoder = JSONDecoder()
 let obj = try! decoder.decode(Welcome.self, from: jsonData!)
```

**IF you have still problem let me know**

Comment: Yea, still don't quite understand. My function suppose to be called with a file name. But now how can I call it?